# Ripple's fees per transaction

Tags: transaction-fees, ripple

I have Toast Wallet in order to store my XRP properly. Now I want to perform my first transaction from my wallet to my exchange in order to understand how it works.

In a note of the Toast Wallet is written: 
**"The Ripple Network requires a minimum 20 XRP balance at all times and charges fees based on congestion even for failed transactions"**

Do you know how much are the charges fees more or less and if even in my case I have to pay that?

With what probability I receive a failed transaction? (supposing I'm typing all address and informations required well) .. [EG If there is a lot of traffic in the network is possible that I receive a refund and so I lost my fees?

How many XRPs can I transfer? Can I transfer only 1 XRP? (obviously I must have 20 XRPs on my balance wallet)

Thanks for the ansewrs,
Marco.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english but I'm Italian :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current minimum transaction cost required by the network for a standard transaction is 0.00001 XRP (10 drops). It sometimes increases due to higher than useal load.

Comment: Ok Thanks so much for the answer. What about the other questions? Do you know about them?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check your exchange's Deposits page (in your account) to check if they have any deposit fees or minimums. Usually they don't.

Also be *very* sure that you read about whether they specify an address **tag** that you must use!

If so, then the XRP address itself is the exchange's XRP address, and only the tag identifies which of their customers the deposit is for.

If not, then they likely will have a warning that sending XRP (or Ripple) to their exchange will reserve 20 XRP in that wallet. In effect, they are generating a unique Ripple wallet for you.